# Unable to find a version of 'Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs' that is compatible with

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, azure, nuget

Need help trying to escape Nuget Hell.

I'm trying to install `Microsoft.Net.Sdk.Functions`, version `1.0.7`, which has a dependency on

`Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs (= 2.0.1-beta4)`

In my `packages.config` of my project I reference

```
<package id="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs" version="2.1.0" targetFramework="net461" />
```

and in the `packages` of my solution I have

```
Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.2.1.0
```

I get the error

```
Unable to find a version of 'Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs' that is compatible with 'Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions 1.0.7 constraint: Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs (= 2.1.0-beta4)'.
```

when trying to install `Microsoft.Net.Sdk.Functions`.

What gives? Something to do with needing `-beta4`? Because when I look in `Nuget` at `Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs`, there is no version suffixed `-beta4`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Microsoft.Net.Sdk.Functions 1.0.7 is tied to a single version of the Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs version 2.1.0-beta4. If you have any other version of Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs installed then you cannot install Microsoft.Net.Sdk.Functions 1.0.7.

```
  <group targetFramework=".NETFramework4.6">
    <dependency id="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs" version="[2.1.0-beta4]" exclude="Build,Analyzers" />
    <dependency id="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions" version="[2.1.0-beta4]" exclude="Build,Analyzers" />
    <dependency id="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Http" version="[1.0.0-beta4]" exclude="Build,Analyzers" />
    <dependency id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="[9.0.1]" exclude="Build,Analyzers" />
    <dependency id="System.ValueTuple" version="4.3.0" exclude="Build,Analyzers" />
  </group>
```

The square brackets around the version indicate that only that specific version is supported. Without the square brackets, such as with System.ValueTuple, indicates that the version needed is that version or higher.

So to get that version of Microsoft.Net.Sdk.Functions to install you would need to uninstall Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs 2.1.0 you have installed.

There are other options, such as installing Microsoft.Net.Sdk.Functions 1.0.8 which depends on Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs 2.1.0, which you have installed.

On nuget.org the Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs 2.1.0-beta4 NuGet package does exist - https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs/2.1.0-beta4 - I am guessing you do not have pre-release checked when searching for this NuGet package.